# How do I sort multiple columns and then cut out two columns

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I have the file

```
6 0 stephen
5 1 john
4 2 margaret
2 3 jack
```

I've been using `cat age_names | sort -n -r age_names.txt`

I want it to display the peoples names in descending order of age, whilst only displaying their names

Answer (score 1):

try
`sort -n -r  age_names.txt | cut -d' ' -f3`

Your sort is correct (assuming the first column is ages).  The cut command specifies that the delimiter is a space (' '), and removes all but the third column, which appears to contain the name.

Answer (score 1):

Consisdering age is at first column and tested with below command ,worked fine

```
sort -k1 -nr file.txt | awk '{print $NF}'
```